# Error: function undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the following Error in chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: buildPopup is not defined
```

but I am defining it in my head:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/info.js"></script>
</head>
```

info.js:

```
function showPopup()
{
    $("#popup").animate({
        "height": "500px",
        "width": "500px",
        "marginLeft": "-250px",
        "marginTop": "-250px",
        "opacity": "1"
    }, 500);
}
function buildPopup(title, text)
{
    if (document.getElementById("popup")!=undefined)
    {
        destroyPopup();
    }

    var p = document.createElement("div");
p.id = "popup";
p.innerHTML = "<img src=\"//"+window.location.host+"/assets/img/static/X.png\" style=\"float: right;\" onclick\"destroyPopup();\"/><iframe seamless="seamless" frameBorder="0"><h1>"+title+"</h1><br><p>"+text+"</p></iframe>";
p.style = "opacity: 0;position: fixed;z-index: 999;top: 50%;width: 6px;height: 6px;margin-top: -3px;overflow: hidden;left: 50%;margin-left: -3px;background-color: cyan;border: 3px groove red;";
document.body.appendChild(p);
    showPopup();
}
function destroyPopup()
{
    $("popup").remove();
}
```

and I am calling it in body like this:

```
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="buildPopup('Help','This is the Help')">Help</a>
</body>
```

Chrome loads jQuery.js and info.js without errors.

Comment: Share exact code that you have in your `info.js`. may be your function `buildPopup` inside the closure. Otherwise it should work.

Comment: @FizerKhan this is all code in it

Comment: You have issue in the coding.  `seamless="seamless"`. Then it must be `escaped`.  `seamless=\"seamless\"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in your code, so the functions will never be created. That's why you get that error message.

You are missing a `+` in this part of the code:

```
..." + window.location.host "...
```

It should be:

```
..." + window.location.host + "...
```

You have some quotation marks that are not escaped here:

```
<iframe seamless="seamless" frameBorder="0">
```

It should be:

```
<iframe seamless=\"seamless\" frameBorder=\"0\">
```

When you have fixed those, you will face the next problem, which several have already pointed out. You can't use `document.write` once the page is completely loaded.

Comment: @user3412531: There was actually more that one error. I have added that above.

Comment: yeah I forgot to escape the quotation marks (facepalm*3)

Answer (score 2):

You CAN NOT use document.write after the page load! So what will happen is when you call it again, the page will just have the pop up code.

You should be be using appendChild to add new elements after the page load.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.id = "popup";
newDiv.className = "UseAClassNotInlineStyle";
newDiv.innerHTML = "<p>BOOM</p>";
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

or since you are using jQuery, you can just replace the line

```
//document.write(h);
$(h).appendTo(document.body);
```

NOW for why the code does not run. I pasted the code into the console and you get the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string fiddle.jshell.net/:38
```

Looking at line 38 I see

```
var h = "<div id=\"popup\" style=\"opacity: 0;position: fixed;z-index: 999;top: 50%;width: 6px;height: 6px;margin-top: -3px;overflow: hidden;left: 50%;margin-left: -3px;background-color: cyan;border: 3px groove red;\"><img src=\"//"+window.location.host"/assets/img/static/X.png\" style=\"float: right;\" onclick\"destroyPopup();\"/><iframe seamless="seamless" frameBorder="0"><h1>"+title+"</h1><br><p>"+text+"</p></iframe></div>";
```

Now looking at the code you will see that there is an error in that line where you are adding the host.

Always look at the console when developing!

Comment: no. This isn't the problem. I commented it out and: Uncaught ReferenceError: buildPopup is not defined

Comment: Well it will be a problem if you reuse it.